# Bind jQuery Keypress() to Polymer paper-input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, polymer, shadow-dom

I'm using the [Polymer](http://polymer-project.org/) framework for a site I'm working on, and I want to bind jQuery's `keypress()` to a Polymer `<paper-input>` element. I tried binding it directly to the element, via

**HTML**

```
<paper-input id="whatever" label="Example"></paper-input>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#whatever").keypress(function(){
     console.log("It worked!");
});
```

I'm aware of the fact that Polymer uses shadow DOM elements, and so the `<input>` tag is seperate from the actual `<paper-input>` tag.

One approach would be something like `$("#whatever").children()` and somehow filter for an `<input>` tag, but I feel that is not the best practice for Polymer.

Either way, I need some way of binding that keypress event to the input.

Comment: I'm not sure jsFiddle supports shadow DOM/Polymer does it?

Comment: You can link to external resources in the left menu. (Must admit I've never used Polymer, but I assume it works like any HTML/JS library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late, but I did had the same issues with web component tester. It turns out Polymer now has a neat component iron-test-helpers which contains a script mock-interactions.js

Use keyEventOn like so:

**Javascript**

```
MockInteractions.keyEventOn(
    Polymer.dom(myEl.root).querySelector('#filter-input'), 'keypress', 13);
```

for firing an keypress event with keycode 13 to the paper input with id 'filter-input'